# What "night" is Hawkins referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-2018

In the slasher movie *Halloween* (2018), a vehicle carrying mentally disabled people including Michael Meyers flipped over the side of the road. They all ended up scattered all over the road. After the incident, Sheriff Barker showed a package to Hawkins:

> Sheriff Barker: It's a hospital gown.
>
> Hawkins: State-issued.
>
> Sheriff Barker: Get on the phone to Smith's Grove. Confirm the match.
>
> Hawkins: You know I was there **that night**. You know. I was there.

What "night" is Hawkins referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hawkins is referring to the night of the very first *Halloween* film, in which Michael Myers first went on the rampage. According to TV Tropes:

> [Hawkins] was the first deputy on the scene after Loomis shot Michael off the balcony in the original [film], and stopped the doctor finishing Michael off. Now that Michael's come home and the bodycount is rising, he's come to view this as a mistake and is willing to finish Michael off by any means necessary.